# Two threads invoking a static function - synchronization issues?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

(I am using Java!) I have two threads t1 and t2. Each thread reads from a Socket inputstream by invoking a **public static** function as follows:

```
public static byte[] readSocket(DataInputStream dis, Logger log) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[100]; 
        if(dis.read(byteArray, 0, 100)!=-1)
        {
            return byteArray;
        }
    }
```

Will there be a synchronization problem if

1. the inputstream is from different sockets (i.e. t1 reads from a different socket and t2 from another).
2. the inputstream is same for both threads t1 and t2.

Comment: Please show the *complete* method - that wouldn't currently compile.

Comment: I'm guessing this is some sort of homework? Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Trying and finding out is pretty hard when the goal is to know if the code is thread-safe or not. You might try 100 times and not have any problem, and then use the code on another machine and see it fail miserably.

Comment: Nothing like a homework, just stumbled upon this question and couldnt figure out the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not cause a data race. If you are calling the same method on different threads, each thread has a different copy of the method on its own stack. Therefore, local variables inside the method exist on each thread's stack with different copies.

So, your only problem can appear if the `DataInputStream` which is an external parameter is shared or not. If not, then you have no problems. The fact that the method is static does not influence in any way what I've said above.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is completely stateless (at least the part you shown us), so calling it from different threads is OK as soon as its arguments may be used from multiple threads.

The documentation of DataInputStream says:

> DataInputStream is not necessarily safe for multithreaded access

So, if both threads use different DataInputStream instances, you'll be fine. If they use the same one, then you'll have problems: you'll need to synchronize the access to the stream yourself.

Comment: But the function readSocket is static, there will be only one copy of this method. the threads might end up in race condition. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @hoshang.varshney: it does not matter if the method is static, each thread will have a different copy on its own stack. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, if the streams are from different sockets then it's thread safe.
2. Yes. Quote from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

> DataInputStream is not necessarily safe for multithreaded access. Thread safety is optional and is the responsibility of users of methods in this class.

Answer (score 0):

1. No so long as the method does not share any higher-than-method-scope fields (where is `byteArray` instantiated?)
2. Yes

Comment: Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: Thread issues result from use of shared resources (variables, IO, streams, etc). If the method is only using method-scope variables (variables that are on the stack not the heap) then they are not shared access invocations of the method. For 2, see other's responses.